# Let $X$ the number of random numbers selected of $\{0,1,2,...,9\}$ independently until the 0 comes out. find the probability function.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ the number of random numbers selected of $\{0,1,2,...,9\}$ independently until the 0 comes out. find the probability function.

**My work:**
Let $X=$"random number selected" 
The sample space $S=\{b,ab,aab,...\}$ where $b=0$ and $a\in \{1,2,...,9\}$

Let $p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a probability function.

Note possible values $X$ can take is $X=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ where $X=9$ can be taken only if $0$ never appear before.

Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Today I learned the word "aleatory". It means "random", and comes from "alea", the Latin word for dice.

Comment: What is the probability to select the sequence $a$ or $aaa$?

Comment: @callculus is i take a number and that number is not 0, then i take other number, and that number is not 0, that number i called "a"

Comment: "i take a number and that number is not 0" What is the probability for that?

Comment: $1/9$ no? @callculus

Comment: Not really. You have 10 possible outcomes. 9 of these outcomes are favorable. I color red the favorable outcomes: $0,\color{red}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}$

Comment: True, you have reason. then $p(x)=\frac{10-x}{10}$ where $x\in\{0,...,9\}$? @callculus

Comment: It is much more simple. You have 10 possible outcomes. 9 of these outcomes are favorable. Then we use the classical definition of probability: $\frac{\text{# of favorable outcomes}}{\text{# of possible outcomes}}=\frac{9}{10}=0.9$ This is the probability to select not a 0: $a$. Then what is the probability to select $aaa$?

Comment: oh... thanks @callculus very glad for your answer.

Comment: @Bvss12 You´re welcome. Do you have already found out the probabilty function?

Comment: Consider geometric distribution.